# Vim custom syntax highlighting background only

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I want to customize syntax highlighting in Vim (GUI version). There is an existing syntax file for my language. I want to add to that syntax highlighting a background colour to each line if that line starts with `>`. I figured out that I can basically achieve this by

```
:syntax match Output /^>.*$/
```

and adding

```
:hi Output guibg=LightBlue
```

to the colourscheme. The background of the text in these `Output` lines gets coloured then in light blue, but it overrides the foreground colour as well. So most of the syntax highlighting disappears. How can I keep the foreground syntax highlighting in these lines?

Also: Is there a way to extend the highlighting of the background to the end (right end of the screen) of these lines?

Comment: This is a good question. I fear the answer is probably no to both but hopefully someone will prove me wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to preserve the syntax, I'm matching lines starting with `{`

```
:hi Output guibg=LightBlue
:match Output '\%>0v{.*'
```

[image]

**Edit:** since you want the opposite you need

```
:match Output '^[^<].*$'
```

[image]

Comment: Works (in opposite order). Is the first line more than a regular expression, such as mine?  Any idea whether highlighting the whole line could be realized with syntax highlighting?

Comment: I'm looking around, but can't find.  With the regexes we match `^.*$` so it makes sense to highlight until the `\r` char is, and not until the window size.  Maybe there is something related to `:set ve=all` but not sure.

Comment: the regex I'm using matches `\%` everything `>` after `0v` virtual column zero, then `{.*` to match the content beginning with {.

Comment: I see. Found that <code>:match</code> versus <code>:syntax match</code> makes the difference. The first, it seems, can only be used if the file was loaded.

Comment: @rembremading:  You can use filetype auto-command: `autocmd FileType <your-language-filetype> match Output /^>.*$/`

Comment: @ib that's a good idea.  What do you think about padding spaces until specific size to fill the horizontal line? Certaintly, works, and before writing you can remove the padding, but it will be like working with `:set ve=all`

Comment: How to achieve this in non-gui vim and for highlights applied with matchadd? Whenever I call matchadd with ctermbg=value the foreground color (also set by a diferent matchadd regex) is reset :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
:hi Output guibg=LightBlue guifg=NONE
```

Comment: I get in vim.gtk -g: "E254: Kann die Farbe None nicht zuweisen". Translating to english: Cannot assign colour None.

Comment: Needed to be in all caps. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks, I just found myself that the command doesn't complain with NONE, but I still get the result described above. Note that I put the highlight command to the beginning of the colourscheme file and enter the syntax command in the editor.  May it depend on the order?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I misunderstood your question. Ordering shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you're looking for is with the `:match` command as Eric Fortis has pointed out.

The only way I know of to achieve this with syntax highlighting will require you to match the entire line as you are currently doing. You will then need to specify, using the `contains=...` modifier, which syntax elements can be in your line. I'm also pretty sure these elements will need to have the `contained` attribute assigned to them. This way any element found in your line i.e matched by the `.*` will preserve it's highlighting.

See `:help :syn-contains` for more.